# Using Ifstream to add numbers from text file to a C Style Array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, text, ifstream

I am having trouble with the title above. I have tried the following but it does not act in the correct behaviour.

```
void ArrayIntStorage::read(ifstream& in)
{
    if(in.is_open())
    {
        while(!in.eof())
        {
            in.getline(arrayStorage, sizeof(in));
        }
    }
}

ofstream& ArrayIntStorage::write(ofstream &out) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof arrayStorage; i++)
    {
        out << arrayStorage[i] << endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

I am a novice at C++ programming, so I am probably doing something stupid. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is arrayStorage? And what is the format of the file?

Comment: What is your expected behavior, and what are you actually getting?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess that you are reading/writing an array of integers.  It appears that you might be incorrectly reading the sizeof(in), rather than the sizeof(arrayStorage) in your read method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.  For starters, you
don't show us the declaration of `arrayStorage`, so we have to
guess it: I'll guess `int arrayStorage[N]`, (where `N` is some
constant).  Following that, for reading:

- It's never correct to use `istream::eof` in a loop.  This
  function only has meaning once input has failed; before
  that, it can return `false` when there is nothing else to
  read, and `true` even though the last input succeeded.  The
  function you're interested in is `fail`, which is what is
  called indirectly whenever the `istream` is used in
  a context which requires a `bool`.
- `getline` requires a `char[]`, and reads characters, not
  int's.

If all the file contains is these int's, the standard idiom
for reading them would be:

```
for (int i = 0; in && i < N; ++ i) {
    in >> arrayStorage[i];
}
```

In practice, you'll probably want a bit more: is it an error if
the file doesn't contain enough int's?  if it contains too many?
And you'll want to verify *after* the failure that the failure
was due to end of file, and not some random gibberish in the
file.  Or maybe you want (or need) to validate the format more,
ensuring that there is never more than one int in a line.

Your output function looks almost OK; the last index should be `N`, and not `sizeof arrayStorage` (which returns the number of bytes in the array, not the number of elements).  Later, downstream,
you'll want to check that there has been no errors *after*
closing the file; there's nothing more frustrating than
a program which says it's succeeded, when in fact only part of
the data made it to disk.